# Why does "value ^= true;" work?

Tags: java, boolean

I found that `value ^= true;` works for changing an boolean through false and true, I would like to understand why it works and what the ^ does, Thanks

Comment: ^ is the XOR operator in java. if output is expected to be true, it makes it false. In case of false, it makes it true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` is a bitwise XOR. `^=` is a bitwise XOR [compound assignment operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2), exactly as you might do when incrementing an integer: `x += 3`

So your expression is equivalent to `value = value XOR true`.

Answer (score 2):

It is bitwise exclusive OR and assignment operator.

value ^= true is equivalent to value = value ^ true

Binary XOR Operator copies the bit if it is set in one operand but not both.

example
a = 0011 1100
b = 0000 1101

a^b = 0011 0001

Answer (score 0):

`^` is the bitwise `XOR` operator in many C like languages. The `XOR` operator works as follows:

[image]

`true` is `1` and `false` is `0`, so whenever you `XOR` two bits that are different it evaluates to `true` otherwise `false`. You can easily experiment with bit operations using your calculator app, just switch to programmer mode.